# Are there any virtualization solutions that work on a VIA C3 processor?

Tags: virtualization, mini-itx

I love my VIA C3 ([Nehemiah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VIA_C3#Nehemiah_cores)) based server, but as far as I can tell it's very hard to find a virtualization solution that works on this processor, since it doesn't support the same instruction sets as Intel/AMD processors of the time.

Are there any options at all?

Comment: C3, Mini-ITX "server". hehehe. :)  What OS's are involved (host/guest)? What are you trying to virtualize? - Also be warned, since that's an older chip (c.2001) with no virtualization technologies to speak (that I know of) of it's going to be Super-Slow for most VM configurations.

Comment: Debian host & guest. It's mainly gonna host some PHP websites, and snapshots would help greatly. Hopefully processing will be less of a bottleneck than RAM and HD I/O, and they are covered fairly well. @techie007

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Apparently [Virtualbox](http://www.virtualbox.org/) can.

From [Virtualbox tips](http://blog.richeton.com/2009/05/04/virtualbox-tips/) :

> **Q:** Does Virtualbox require CPU with virtualization capabilities ?
>
> **A:** NO. Virtualbox can even run on VIA C3 processors (on 486 linux kernel
>   for instance).

Comment: Really? That's great news. There's still a use for it yet!

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to use pretty much any commercially available (desktop) virtualisation (e.g. non-hypervisor) program - Just do not expect anything fast!

Take a look at [Virtualbox](http://www.virtualbox.org), [Virtual PC](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/), or [VMWare Workstation](http://www.vmware.com/products/workstation/)

Comment: My worry is that the C3 might not even be a 686, but I could be confusing it with an old laptop I got around the same time. It's been quite some time since I installed anything new on this server. ;-)

Comment: You can't really compare...,  it is x86 compatible and that is all that matters for virtualisation.

Answer (score 3):

You certainly wouldn't be able to use anything that relied on VT-x or AMD-V, but I don't see why something like VirtualBox running inside Linux shouldn't operate.